# Publisher for ardrone

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, publisher, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
i have a problem with publishing sth. to the ardrone. I am using ROS Hydro and this is a part of my code for one of the publishers i am using:

(in the header-file)

ros::Publisher land_pub;

(in cpp-file)

ros::NodeHandle nh;
land_pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Empty>("ardrone/land", 1);

(with a button-klick of my joypad i want to publish this message:)

std_msgs::Empty emptymsg;
land_pub.publish(emptymsg);

But when i am using "rostopic echo ardrone/land" (or takeoff) nothing is published and my ardrone does nothing... but if i am publishing under this topic via terminal it works... could anybody help me solving this, please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112396/publisher--for-ardrone/) by [Cookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9861/cookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved by myself :)

---

Originally posted by [Cookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9861/cookie/) with karma: 16 on 2013-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0